# Mongoose Best way to query documents, process on results, then delete afterwards?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to gather all documents that match my query, then use a value inside the document (in this case to send a request to another service), and then finally delete the document afterwards.

My current set up is like this:

```
// Check availability
 function checkIfAvailable() {
    console.log('Attempting to purge non available documents...');

    // Find all with availability with false
    MetaFile.find({availability: false}, (err, result) => {
        // Print error if failed
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            // Go through each file in result array
            result.forEach(file => {
                try {
                    // Then request to delete from S3 service
                    await axios.post(process.env.URL_DUD +'delete', {
                        type: "FileDeleted",
                        data: {
                            fileId: file.fileId,
                        },
                    });
                }
                // Catch Error when sending axios request 
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

                // TODO Potentially Add a request to delete to the USER section
            });
        }
    });

    
    MetaFile.deleteMany({availability: false}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    
}
```

So what I am doing here is:

1. using the find method to find all documents that match the query
2. Go through the resulting array and send a request out using the value from within the document
3. using the deleteMany method to delete the documents using the same query

I'm wondering if there was a better approach than this.